# How to structure JavaScript for this form to submit data?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created this form to enter the following data:

- Name
- Email
- GPA #

I then have a submit button in the form but the information does not submit the information and I do not know why. I have added the HTML and CSS but I am not sure how to begin structuring the JavaScript for this Form to submit.

If anyone has any suggestions on what JavaScript I need to add to make sure that this form submits, I would appreciate it.

```css
 /* Samantha Hayes, JavaScript Project, ISLT/7356 Interactive Web Deisgn with JavaScript Project */

 /* Format for all pages and lists and navigation */

body {background-color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000}
              
/* the styles for the elements */
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #FFDF00;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
nav a:focus, nav a:hover, article a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

/* the styles for the reflection */
header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FFDF00;
 padding: 1.5em 0;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
}
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFDF00;
}

main {
 clear: left;
 padding: 0 20px 20px;
 width: 525px;
 float: right;
}
main p {
 padding-bottom: .5em;
}
main blockquote {
 padding: 0 2em;
 font-style: italic;
}
main ul {
   list-style-type: none
 padding: 0 0 1.5em 1.25em;
}
main li {
 padding-bottom: .35em;
}
```

```html
<!--
 Samantha Hayes
 ISLT 4356/7356 Interactive Web Design with JavaScript Project
 December 2018
-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
<script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Fill out the following Boxes</legend>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <span>*</span><br>
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     <span>*</span><br>
  <label for="gpa">GPA:</label>
  <input type="text" name="gpa" id="gpa" placeholder="#.##">
  <span>*</span><br>
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit GPA">
  <form action="submit.html" method="get"
   name="submit_form" id="submit_form">
  </form>
  <div id="dialog" title="GPA Submitted" style="display: none;">
   <p>Thank you for submitting your GPA to your teacher! Please move to the reflection part of the activity.</p>
  </div><br>      
 </fieldset>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why do you have form only with button? All required fields must be in it.

Comment: And we dont need the whole page. Only the part causing the problem.

Comment: what do you want to do with the data when it is submitted?

Comment: please provide a [mcve], don't just throw all the code you have

Comment: I would like the data to be collected in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You should include all your elements within form element rather than just the button.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
<!--
    Samantha Hayes
    ISLT 4356/7356 Interactive Web Design with JavaScript Project
    December 2018
-->
<title>Homeroom GPA Calculatiion: Step 4</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
    <script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="submit.html" method="get"
                name="submit_form" id="submit_form">

        <!-- Nav -->
            <nav>
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a href="hayes_java_project.html">Home: GPA Calculation Tutorial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_why.html"> Why Calculate your GPA?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_1.html">Step 1: Document Your Grades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_2.html">Step 2: Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_3.html">Step 3: Average GPA Point Total to Get GPA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_4.html">Step 4: Submit GPA for Teachers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

    <h1>HHS Homeroom GPA Calculation: Step 4</h1>
    <h2>Submit GPA for Teachers</h2>
    <p>Using the boxes below, enter your email and your calculated GPA. If you have a request for help, please enter it in the second box below with your email address.</p>
        <br>            
    <nav>

            <fieldset>
            <legend>Fill out the following Boxes</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <span>*</span><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            <span>*</span><br>
            <label for="gpa">GPA:</label>
            <input type="text" name="gpa" id="gpa" placeholder="#.##">
            <span>*</span><br>
            <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit GPA">


            <div id="dialog" title="GPA Submitted" style="display: none;">
                <p>Thank you for submitting your GPA to your teacher! Please move to the reflection part of the activity.</p>
            </div><br>          
        </fieldset>
    </nav>
    <!--button to next page-->
<br>
    <div class="widget">
        <p>Go on to <button><a href="project_reflection.html">Reflection</a></button></p>
    </div>
<br>
 <footer>
        <small><i>Page created by Samantha Hayes.<br>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 <br>
        Please <a href="mailto:shayes@cpsk12.org">e-mail</a> me with any questions.<br>
        Last updated on December 2018. </i></small>
    </footer>
 </form>
</body>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>

</html>
```